# Converting yesterdays date to a string SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am trying to simply cast yesterdays date (in the 23 format) to a string. I keep getting error "Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type."

Any ideas?

```
DECLARE @yesterday CHAR;
SET @yesterday = convert(varchar,getdate()-1,23);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @yesterday varchar(100)
SET @yesterday = CONVERT(varchar(100),DATEADD(day,-1,getdate()),23)
SELECT @yesterday
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` is equivalent to `char(1)`. So after your `set` statement, the `@yesterday` variable will have the value `'2'` - the first character of your formatted datetime. You must be attempting to put this into a `smalldatetime`, which of course fails, because `'2'` is not a valid `smalldatetime`. You should be using `char(10)` for date format 23.